# Buggy Bullet Collisions Consistency in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Bullet collisions in my FPS project are fairly buggy. That is, sometimes, bullets are registering collisions, and other times they don't. It appears that the difference between the two happens to do with the location we're standing between ourselves and the target, but sometimes that isn't the case (i.e. we move around a bit back to the same spot we just shot at and collisions might work again).

For the sack of simplicity to solving this problem, I'll leave a link to a massive reddit post I made about this problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/18g4dr8/comment/ke7x2k7/?context=3

The current status of the problem is that the bug is still in effect and nothing's really changed since my last test. If you guys require more info on the matter, lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your current code, it's hard for me to judge, but to me it sounds like a case of "tunneling". You can find a very good explanation [here] (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192403).

In short: Your object is still in front of the collision object in one frame and behind it in the next frame. So it never actually collides/triggers.

In Unity there are multiple ways to solve this. I will present the 2 most simple and common ones. In most cases the **Ray Casting** approach is the best one.

**Continuous Collisions**

Adjust the collider settings of the objects and set the "Collision detection" property to "Continuous" or "Continuous dynamic", then Unity can perform more accurate collision checks, especially with fast-moving objects this is necessary.

**Ray Casting**

Basically, you must perform raycasting from the last frame to the current frame position in order to avoid tunneling problems. So that the ray will hit all objects between the last frame and this frame. Example:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private float bulletSpeed = 1000.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;

        // Move the bullet to its next position
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed);

        // Perform raycast from last position to current position
        CheckForCollisions();
    }

    void CheckForCollisions()
    {
        // Calculate the direction the bullet moved
        Vector3 movedVector = transform.position - lastFramePosition;

        // Cast a ray from the last position to the current position
        // `QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide` including triggers
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(lastPosition, movedVector.normalized, out hit, movedVector.magnitude, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide))
        {
            HandleCollision(hit.collider);
        }
    }

    void HandleCollision(Collider otherCollider)
    {
        Debug.Log("Bullet hit: " + otherCollider.gameObject.name);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I tried out changing Collision Detection from Continous to Continous Dynamic, which yielded basically no difference, so I tried out your raycasting technique as well but I've run into some issues. There's some errors involving the parameters we set inside our raycast (i.e. movedVector.normalized is being interpretated as the int layerMask parameter, but we can't convert a float to an int here). 

Here's a hatebin with my collision script for my bullets, everything involving the raycasting is in void Update(): https://hatebin.com/jfvycpayqm